# Prove that there is a $n$-bit grey code for all positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I understand how this proof works ie. if you want to get $(n+1)$-bit grey code you just had to append $0$ to all $n$-bit grey string then add the reverse order of the $n$-bit grey string with $1$ appended to the reverse.

But I'm having trouble constructing a mathematical proof of this. Say that I wanted to prove this by induction, I know how to do the base case but cant formulate the induction step. (in mathematical terms at least).

Like how to a denote to a sequence in reverse order?

Comment: Just make up a notation.  For example, if $s$ is a bit sequence $s^R$ is the reverse of $s$.  If you don't like that one, make up your own.

Comment: Ah ok. Still cant seem to finish the induction step. Say I say the sequence S(n) holds and I say S(n+1) = 0S(n) + 1S^R(n). Where do I go from there?

Comment: Write down the definition of a Gray code.  What do you have to prove about the putative $n+1$-bit code?  Are there are parts of the statement that are clear to you?  What parts are unclear?  Do a small example, and see why those parts are true in that case.  If you still can't finish the proof, edit the question to show how far you have gotten, and where you are stuck.  You'll learn a lot more by doing this than by just reading someone else's solution, even if you end up having to ask for help to finish.  I know you've been told this before, but it's still true.